# How to connect to a Tor network?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection:

06/03/2016 03:59:11.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:11.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:11.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:11.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 03:59:12.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
06/03/2016 03:59:12.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
06/03/2016 03:59:13.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
06/03/2016 03:59:13.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
06/03/2016 03:59:14.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
06/03/2016 03:59:15.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 03:59:19.800 [WARN] Our clock is 1 days, 3 hours, 0 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-06-04 07:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
06/03/2016 03:59:19.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 03:59:20.600 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 03:59:47.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 03:59:47.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:47.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 03:59:48.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:48.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:48.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 03:59:48.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:01:17.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 04:06:21.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 04:16:32.100 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 04:25:15.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:25:15.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:25:15.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:25:15.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
06/03/2016 04:25:16.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:25:16.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:25:16.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:25:16.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:25:18.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:25:18.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:25:18.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:25:18.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
06/03/2016 04:28:27.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:28:27.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:28:27.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:28:27.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:28:29.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (fresh): $BF0103DFB2BD2C690E0DB2CA472989ADA4A79826~Unnamed at 24.52.20.214 
06/03/2016 04:28:29.300 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 04:28:30.100 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (fresh): $C3EFF90B2703D5DA4E49BD2002268DE2B0E7E0EF~Unnamed at 37.218.246.75 
06/03/2016 04:28:30.100 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
06/03/2016 04:36:37.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:36:37.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2016 04:36:37.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2016 04:36:38.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: From your logs:

```06/03/2016 03:59:19.800 [WARN] Our clock is 1 days, 3 hours, 0 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-06-04 07:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings!```

Check that your date, time and timezone are accurate. Tor requires a reasonably accurate date and time to work.